# can an app post a message into yammer as itself

Tags: yammer

The docs seem to indicate that once a user authenticates via oauth to an app, the app can post messages on behalf of the user.

What I want to be able to do is post messages as the app. For example the app might search the web for some trending news and than post this trending news into a Yammer group called trending news. However, currently it seems that the app can only post to such as a group as an authenticated user say "john doe". Is there anyway instead that the app can post to this group as user "app-trending news"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Messages have to be associated with a user. Therefore you have to create an "app-trending news" user. This is "by design" otherwise machine generated content would drown out user conversations. It's a fine balance but users react negatively to content posted from "bot" users like this, or don't engage with the content they post in.

If you have machine generated updates you can post to the Activity Stream and include a message there.